# how to install oci8 on suse linux Enterprise 11 sp 4

Tags: linux, suse

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php5/extensions/oci8.so' - libnnz11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I have followed many tutorials on OCI8 installation but no luck so far.

Following are the details of the system

PHP version is  php -v
PHP 5.5.16 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Installed 
pecl install oci8-2.0.12

Database:

Oracle 11 g
Oracle Instant Client: oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm
                       oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm

extension=oci8.so and extension_dir=/usr/lib64/php5/extensions added in /etc/sysconfig/apache2 config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your library search path to the Instant Client directory.  The easiest way is to use ldconfig.  This is shown in the Instant Client install instructions https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst

Comment: It worked, thanks @Christoper, now the error is changed and i am looking into code now.